# What is the maximum number of players in Texas Hold'em?

Tags: texas-hold-em

I've been told the maximum number of players at a Texas Hold'em table is 10. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ideal max number at a regular-size table is 9 players and a dealer. 10 is also not uncommon. Some larger tournaments will occasionally place 11 at a table in the early stages until the field is narrowed a little.  Any more than that and you'll have a game that is super tight, both in terms of the poker and the space available to you. The theoretical max at a table is limited only by the number of cards available in the deck.  52 cards, and 8 are used up as part of the board (5 cards shown plus 3 total burn cards). That leaves 44 cards remaining, and each player gets 2 of them, so I guess you could have 22 players if you had a big table and skinny people. Of course, a game like this would be no fun for anyone, dealer or players.

Comment: Agree. I would like to add that the more the number of players increase, the tighter you can play because the blinds will come slower to you.

Comment: And no (or only one) burn card(s) would allow for 23 players total.  Still, dealing out nearly the whole deck, even with everyone playing super-tight it seems that somebody would have a good enough starting hand to open more often than not.

Comment: At 22 hand someone would have  pocket aces like 1/10 hands.

Answer (score 3):

In the 80s I played in clubs that routinely spread 13-14 hands on a big table (often a "violin" table more commonly used for Baccarat). That's very unusual nowadays, since casinos know that slows down the rake, so most spread only 9 or 10 now.

Theoretically, without burns, you could have 23 players. Early Internet games on IRC would spread a tournament this way, and it was a quite playable game.

Answer (score 0):

the community cards need to be eight, 4 on the flop, two on the turn and river. leaving 44 cards for player hands or max of 22 players, this might be interesting online, but in a casino, you would likely be bored to distraction IMHO. this is enpough for an 11 handed Omaha game.

Answer (score -1):

10 Is max, more players would just kill the game... If you play poker for a longer time I think you would agree with me. I prefer to play 6max on cash game, it's faster and more skilled.

Think if 20 people sat on one table. They would rarely pay blinds and everyone would be waiting to hit some strong hand and nobody would play which kill the thinking game of poker.

If you try to play heads up tons of play is around bluffing and exploiting your opponents weaknesses which is very fun.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

More the merrier!  I’m on my 43rd home game,  12 was usually my standard midweek turnout at a single table.  That was never a problem - also sometimes a couple more would just join

I have a 10c ante with 25c small 50c big blind. So the more players actually made a decent pot - last man standing still gets some coin even with folds

Having more than 09 is a good idea in my real world experience

22 is the max if you spent the whole deck!

Answer (score -1):

I think above 10 would start to kill the games, you've got 40 cards out already, those that call with marginal K9, Q8, A5 are disadvantages because what's probably left with the 12 cards left is garbage. The chances of a pair is reduced to 1 in 10 resulting in raises and folds pre flop and very little action.